# Getting pixel data on setInterval with canvas

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I want to build an animated alphabet, made up of particles. Basically, the particles transform from one letter shape to another.

My idea is to fill the letters as text on canvas real quickly (like for a frame), get the pixel data and put the particles to the correct location on setInterval. I have this code for scanning the screen right now:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    width = ctx.canvas.width,
    height = ctx.canvas.height,

    particles = [],
    gridX = 8,
    gridY = 8;

function Particle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// fill some text
ctx.font = 'bold 80px sans-serif';
ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0';
ctx.fillText("STACKOVERFLOW", 5, 120);

// now parse bitmap based on grid
var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

// use a 32-bit buffer as we are only checking if a pixel is set or not
var buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);

// using two loops here, single loop with index-to-x/y is also an option
for(var y = 0; y < height; y += gridY) {
  for(var x = 0; x < width; x += gridX) {

    //buffer32[] will have a value > 0 (true) if set, if not 0=false
    if (buffer32[y * width + x]) {
      particles.push(new Particle(x, y));
    }
  }
}

// render particles
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

particles.forEach(function(p) {
  ctx.fillRect(p.x - 2, p.y - 2, 4, 4); // just squares here
})
```

But this way I am only showing one word, without any changes throughout the time. Also, I want to set up initially like 200 particles and reorganise them based on the pixel data, not create them on each scan.. How would you rewrite the code, so on every 1500ms I can pass a different letter and render it with particles?

Comment: For the animation, just handle a start / end point, and interpolate inside an animation loop : http://jsbin.com/nomiloleri/1/edit?js,output  For the letter-by-letter feature, there's more work : you have to use measureText, draw on a secondary canvas, getImageData and build a new set of particle for this new letter that you add to the current set of particles. Which requires a bit of organisation not to get messy. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, man! When I draw on a secondary canvas, should it be inserted into the DOM and actually drawn on the screen for this to work, or I can I use it simply to fill text (again, without rendering anything) and get its imageData? Also, why would I add new particles to the particle array for each new letter? How about I make like 100 particles and transform them to a new shape, without making new ones or splicing the particles array? Also, since I'm quite new to JS, can you hint me on how to structure and write such app? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the different parts of this code should be clear enough : There are particles, that can draw and update, fillParticle will spawn particles out of a text string, and spawnChars will get a new part of the text rendered on a regular basis.

It is working quite well, play with the parameters if you wish, they are all at the start of the fiddle.
You might want to make this code cleaner, by avoiding globals and creating classes.

http://jsbin.com/jecarupiri/1/edit?js,output

```
// --------------------
// parameters

var text = 'STACKOVERFLOW';
var fontHeight = 80;
var gridX = 4,
    gridY = 4;
var partSize = 2; 
var charDelay = 400; // time between two chars, in ms
var spead = 80; // max distance from start point to final point
var partSpeed = 0.012;

// --------------------
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    width = ctx.canvas.width,
    height = ctx.canvas.height,
    particles = [];

ctx.translate(0.5,0.5);

// --------------------
// Particle class
function Particle(startX, startY, finalX, finalY) {
    this.speed = partSpeed*(1+Math.random()*0.5);
    this.x = startX;
    this.y = startY;

    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
    this.finalX =finalX;
    this.finalY =finalY;
    this.parameter = 0;
    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x - partSize*0.5, this.y - partSize*0.5, partSize, partSize);
    };
    this.update = function(p) {
       if (this.parameter>=1) return;
       this.parameter += partSpeed;
       if (this.parameter>=1) this.parameter=1;
       var par = this.parameter;
       this.x = par*this.finalX + (1-par)*this.startX;
       this.y = par*this.finalY + (1-par)*this.startY;
   };
}

// --------------------
// Text spawner

function fillParticle(text, offx, offy,  spread) {
   // fill some text
   tmpCtx.clearRect(0,0,tmpCtx.canvas.width, tmpCtx.canvas.height);
   tmpCtx.font = 'bold ' + fontHeight +'px sans-serif';
   tmpCtx.fillStyle = '#A40';
   tmpCtx.textBaseline ='top';
   tmpCtx.textAlign='left';
   tmpCtx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
   //
   var txtWidth = Math.floor(tmpCtx.measureText(text).width);
   // now parse bitmap based on grid
   var idata = tmpCtx.getImageData(0, 0, txtWidth, fontHeight);

   // use a 32-bit buffer as we are only checking if a pixel is set or not
   var buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);

   // using two loops here, single loop with index-to-x/y is also an option
   for(var y = 0; y < fontHeight; y += gridY) {
     for(var x = 0; x < txtWidth; x += gridX) {
        //buffer32[] will have a value > 0 (true) if set, if not 0=false
        if (buffer32[y * txtWidth + x]) {
           particles.push(new Particle(offx + x+Math.random()*spread - 0.5*spread, 
                                  offy + y+Math.random()*spread - 0.5*spread, offx+x, offy+y));
        }
    }
  }  
  return txtWidth;
}

var tmpCv = document.createElement('canvas');
// uncomment for debug
//document.body.appendChild(tmpCv);
var tmpCtx = tmpCv.getContext('2d');

// --------------------------------
// spawn the chars of the text one by one

var charIndex = 0;
var lastSpawnDate = -1;
var offX = 30;
var offY = 30;

function spawnChars() {
  if (charIndex>= text.length) return;
  if (Date.now()-lastSpawnDate < charDelay) return;
  offX += fillParticle(text[charIndex], offX, offY, spead);
  lastSpawnDate = Date.now();
  charIndex++;                           
}


// --------------------------------

function render() {
   // render particles
   particles.forEach(function(p) { p.draw();
   });  
}

function update() {
   particles.forEach(function(p) { p.update(); } );    
}

// --------------------------------
//  animation
function animate(){
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   render();
    update();
  //
  spawnChars();
}

// launch : 
animate();
```

Comment: @Georgi B. Nikolov: I noticed you've asked quite a few questions and received useful answers here on StackOverflow. Since you are a relatively new user, I would mention that it's traditional on StackOverflow for you to click the checkmark on answers that best fill your question's needs. This checkmark lets answerers know that you've received a good answer and they don't need to try to further answer your question. This checkmark is also a "thank you" to the people who have helped you with answers.